# Arduino-do something only when done read serial?

Tags: arduino

I have some problem with a basic thing here .
When you want to read a serial data as a string, than do something/many things based on that value, you have this problem :

```
  while(Serial.available()) 
      {

      character = Serial.read();
      content.concat(character);
         delay(10); 

        }

             //do something with the value 
             int myInt = content.toInt();
             float myFloat=myInt;
              analogWrite(10,myInt)  ;

              //clear
              content="" ; //i must clear it for the next word !
```

When you clear `content` , than next loop you get content="" ,  **and you dont want to put that value into the analog/what ever you do with it** ,  but **only when** there is a **change** on the serial , than use that new value .

I couldn't find a way to do that .. i dont have a sign when he finish reading the new data(only)

Comment: one solution that i found  that i think is really not elegant, is to set some boolean, and when he finish the while loop, he check if that bool is 1, you do what you want, and set the bool back to 0 , till next while loop. seems very strange for such a simple task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in an if like this:

```
if(!(content == "")) {

    //do something with the value 
    int myInt = content.toInt();
    float myFloat=myInt;
    analogWrite(10,myInt);
    //clear
    content="" ; //i must clear it for the next word !

}
```

You can also pause the code if you want to wait at the top for serial input by putting:

```
while (!(Serial.available())) { }
```

Above your initial serial read code segment

Comment: ITS the same as putting a bollean, but ok .

Comment: Except you are using existing variables, there is no additional Boolean manipulation required throughout the coffee path and I find code like this more readable since it is quite clear this block should only run if "content is not empty"